# Websocket Sampler in Jmeter Script

Tags: sockets, websocket, jmeter

I am trying to load test a chat application developed using Node.js and Socket.io

Overall Scenario is

1. Operator login and wait for the customer to initiate chat
2. Customer initiate chat (from different URL)
3. Operator sees the chat request and take chat
4. chatting takes place
5. Customer ends the chat and operator also submit survey(and ends the chat)

I have recorded the whole scenario using Blazemeter plugin of Chrome
But when I confirm with Chrome developer tool, My recorded script missed the Websocket requests

Now how can I integrate web socket sampler in the script. I mean I am aware  where I need to place the Sampler. 
Actually I have placed as well but my recorded script terminate at the Websocket sampler with following parameter

```
Protocol:WSS, Port: 443; Path: socket.io/1/websocket/${socketid}; 
Request Data: Blank; Reponse Pattern: (.*)
```

And When I observed the Websocket request in the chrome developer tool, there were multiple request-response(messages) for the single Websocket request.

So how can I integrate websocket sampler in my JMeter script, with what configuration/parameter? Is it possible? If not suggest some alternative tool or approach

Comment: I know it's been a while since you asked this question but I think you can check my question which contains answers for your question regarding which JMeter plugin can perform WebSocket testing and a tutorial how to use it:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53865947/1306012